# Understanding purpose of and difference between given recursive functions

Tags: c

Below are the two pieces of code. I could not understand how the pre-decrement operator in the first code functions. And I also could not understand how both of the codes differ in their functionality.

**Code 1:**

```c
int foo (int val) { 
  int x = 0; 
  while (val > 0) {
    x = x + foo(--val);
  }
  return val;
}
```

---

**Code 2:**

```c
int bar (int val) {
  int x = 0;
  while (val > 0) {
    x = x + bar(val - 1);
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Please post all relevant content directly in the question as text, not an external link.

Comment: Add `printf("val: %d\n", val);` as the first line of the function to see why. Also, do you understand the difference between pre-increment and post-increment?

Comment: Please consider the possibility that people might not trust the link you show (me for example). Hence it would be in your interest to provide all info directly here.

Comment: Since the code returns `val`, it will always be either 0 (non-negative input) or what was provided (negative input).  The recursion keeps adding `0` to `x`, so `x` remains `0` too.  It would be accurate to say it is equivalent to `int foo(int val) { return (val < 0) ? val : 0; }`.  In the context of the original question, big enough inputs will cause a stack overflow and abnormal termination.  For the designated `foo(3)` test, it will return 0.  None of the options is accurate, therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the original code:

```
int foo(int val) {
    int x = 0;
    while (val > 0) {
        x = x + foo(val--);  // Post-decrement
    }
    return val;
}
```

When `foo()` calls itself recursively, the value passed to the recursive call is the same as the value passed to the current call, so the program will eventually exceed the stack limit and crash.  It won't terminate normally.

Now consider the revised code:

```
int foo(int val) {
    int x = 0;
    while (val > 0) {
        x = x + foo(--val);  // Pre-decrement
    }
    return val;
}
```

Now the recursion is finite; if `val` is positive, then the recursive call is made with a smaller value, so the recursion stops.  If `val` is negative, there is no recursion, of course.

However, since the code returns `val`, it will always return either 0 (for a non-negative input, because the loop counts down until `val == 0`) or what was provided (for a negative input; the loop body is never executed).  The recursion keeps adding `0` to `x`, so `x` remains `0` too (but it's a 'set but unread' variable so it could be eliminated, and writing `x += foo(val--);` would be more idiomatic C).  It would be accurate to say the revised code is equivalent to:

```
int foo(int val) { return (val < 0) ? val : 0; }
```

Even returning `x` doesn't fix all the problems.  It returns 0 for non-negative inputs and 0 for negative inputs (but it doesn't crash):

```
int foo(int val) {
    int x = 0;
    while (val > 0) {
        x += foo(--val);  // Pre-decrement
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I can't see the code for `bar()` in the question.  When you've added it, let me know and I'll look at how it differs.  There's also no variable `v` in the code; there's `val` and `x`.

Comment: Please add the `bar()` function to the question — not a comment.

Comment: The major and crucial difference is that `bar()` recurses on a smaller value of `val`, whereas `foo()` recurses on the current value of `val`, so it never gets closer to finishing.